# Running a Node.Js script as a custom shortcut

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to create a node script that will run on a keyboard command.
I added a custom keyboard shortcut:

```
node /full/path/index.js
```

Also tried to create an executable bash script that will run the node command and it doesn't work.

bash commands run, but the node doesn't.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Manage to solve it - make the file a node js executable.

Steps:

1) Add a node shabang to the node.js script, usually:

```
#!/bin/env node
```

2) Define custom shortcut command as the full path to the file, i.e:

```
/full/path/to/file/index.js
```

3) Make file executable, using chmod:

```
sudo chmod +x /full/path/to/file/index.js
```

Hope it helps :)